# Segmentation fault when reading file in c in a small file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I got segmentation fault ( core dumped) in c while reading a file.i used this code for milion other files and it workes fine. But this file has 138 lines when others start at 250. So im guessing thats the problem? (the code is on the bottom of my post)its suppose to help me work on the read data so i could do operations on them in the code but whatever i do its just "core dumped"

it breaks here :

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        strtok(line, "\n");
        parseLine(line, &dataList);
    }
```

i already tried :

```
char *line = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( LINE_BUFFER + 1 )
```

instead of

```
 char line[LINE_BUFFER];
```

Heres the part of the code that reads a file :

`````
#define DIFF_BUFFER 99999999

DataLineNode *loadData(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[LINE_BUFFER];
    DataLineNode *dataList = NULL;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("No file '%s'.\n", fileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        strtok(line, "\n");
        parseLine(line, &dataList);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return dataList;
}

````
`````

Comment: *"whatever i do its just "core dumped""* - in case no one told you, that's the default indicator to be followed by "so I ran it under a debugger and found....". Time to do that.

Comment: a buffer size of 99 million seems a bit excessive.  suggest starting with a more reasonable number, like 1024

Comment: OT: regarding: `strtok(line, "\n");`  this has some undesirable side effects.  Suggest:  `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: OT: regarding: printf("No file '%s'.\n", fileName);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) this is not 'necessarily' correct.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  As this will output to `stderr` both you error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: The posted code does not contain enough informatioin to answer the question.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: `LINE_BUFFER` not defined.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE] in which `parseLine` is defined?

Comment: @WhozCraig yea i did that, i just wrote that in other words :"it breaks here : " to be precise i ran it under a debugger and it has a problem here :  parseLine(line, &dataList);

Comment: @user3121023 yes